# How do I use string formatting with explicit character escape codes in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, format

I know that I can print the following:

```
print u'\u2550'
```

How do I do that with the `.format` string method? For example:

```
for i in range(0x2550, 0x257F):
    s = u'\u{04X}'.format(i) # of course this is a syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`unichr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr):

```
s = u'{}'.format(unichr(i))
```

or just plain

```
s = unichr(i)
```

`unichr(integer)` produces a unicode character for the given codepoint.

The `\uxxxx` syntax only works for *string literals*; these are processed by the Python compiler *before running the code*.

Demo:

```
>>> for i in range(0x2550, 0x257F):
...     print unichr(i)
... 
═
║
╒
╓
╔
╕
╖
# etc.
```

If you ever do have literal `\uxxxx` sequences in your strings, you can still have Python turn those into Unicode characters with the `unicode_escape` codec:

```
>>> print u'\\u2550'
\u2550
>>> print u'\\u2550'.decode('unicode_escape')
═
>>> print '\\u2550'.decode('unicode_escape')
═
>>> '\\u2550'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\u2550'
```

In Python 2, you can use this codec on both byte string and `unicode` string values; the output is always a `unicode` string.